# Anaconda not letting me launch Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Trying to Launch Spyder from Anaconda and keep getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/gpoole14/opt/anaconda3/envs/ltcwbb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 21, in
> from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/gpoole14/opt/anaconda3/envs/ltcwbb/bin/spyder", line 11, in
> sys.exit(main())
> File "/Users/gpoole14/opt/anaconda3/envs/ltcwbb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 233, in main
> from spyder.app import mainwindow
> File "/Users/gpoole14/opt/anaconda3/envs/ltcwbb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 59, in
> from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
> File "/Users/gpoole14/opt/anaconda3/envs/ltcwbb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 27, in
> from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'

Comment: Try installing the missing module - see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8952

Comment: What `pyqt` version do you have installed? Do you have a M1/ARM based machine? Maybe try to create a new env using the conda-forge channel. With that you will get also the `pyqtwebengine` package (which is an independent package needed for pyqt > 5.12 to get the `QtWebEngine*` related modules)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block and/or error message in the body of question. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @AlexB Done. Please Help!

Comment: @DanielAlthviz Okay it took me awhile to figure out what you were suggesting but this absolutely worked. Thank you

Comment: Glad you find a way to setup things to prevent the error! Maybe you could add what you ended up doing as a response here

Answer (score 0):

On anaconda prompt, do the following

```
conda uninstall -c anaconda spyder
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

try it, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on my Mac M1. Ultimately it worked as per [Daniel Althviz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15954282/daniel-althviz) comment. Go to Anaconda -> Environments -> 'Not installed', search for `pyqtwebengine` select it and click apply in the right bottom corner.